# Creating a WPF label with ComboBox editor in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

I'm trying to create a wpf Style that will make a label appear as a normal label until it's clicked for editing. When it's clicked, I want it to be a combobox populated by a collection of things from the same object binding. I need this to be as generic as possible for reuse. I'm relatively new to wpf and really am having issues knowing where to look for this. Also, my current solution is stolen from the internet and modified from a similar solution using a textblock editor.

I intend to use this from a DataTemplate in a user control. The label will be within a row of a listbox.

```
<telerik:RadListBox
                Name="FileListBox"
                Margin="2"
                AllowDrop="True"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                ItemsSource="{Binding LeafNodes, Mode=OneWay}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FavoriteTemplateSelector}"
                >
            </telerik:RadListBox>
```

and the DataTemplate.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Project.Presentation;component/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="FavoriteTemplateSelector">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Label 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="{Binding Path=Parent}"
                    Style="{StaticResource EditableLabelComboStyle}"/>
                <!--other controls -->
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

So, my LeafNodes binding from the listbox contains a collection called Categories that I want to use to populate the combobox. Here is the what I have so far in my styles control template. I'm fairly certain that my issue is in my lack of understanding in the ComboBox ItemSource. I'm sure my RelativeSource is wrong, but don't really know where to start.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="EditableComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <ContentPresenter Name="contentHolder" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
        <ContentPresenter.Content>
            <Grid Margin="0">
                <Border Name="nonFocusedBorder"
                    Grid.ZIndex="3" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    />
                <ComboBox Name="editComboBox"
                        Grid.ZIndex="1" Opacity="0"
                        Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        />
                <Border BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="{Binding ElementName=editComboBox, Path=ActualHeight}" Margin="0,0,3,0"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBlock Name="displayTextBox" 
                            Grid.ZIndex="2" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            TextAlignment="Right"
                            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=OneWay}"
                            />
                </Border>
                <Border/>
            </Grid>
        </ContentPresenter.Content>
    </ContentPresenter>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="editComboBox" Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="displayTextBox" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
            <Setter TargetName="editComboBox" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            <Setter TargetName="nonFocusedBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="BorderThickness" Value="0">
            <Setter TargetName="editComboBox" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter TargetName="nonFocusedBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter TargetName="nonFocusedBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="EditableLabelComboStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource EditableComboBoxTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#B5CFFF"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have an easier time making a combo box look like a label until it's clicked or whatever event you want. Make your combo box IsEditable property false initially. Style the combo box using datatriggers to make it look like a label when IsEditable == false. Use EventTriggers (e.g. Click) to set the IsEditable property accordingly, when you set it to TRUE, the IsEditable == False setters should be unset and your combo box will return to normal.

Option 2:
Instead of just putting a border on top of your combobox, also put a textbox. Use a converter on the Visibility of the bottom layer such that when the top layer is Visibility=Collapsed, the bottom is Visible and vice versa. Then you just need to set visibility of the top layer.

Comment: Your first option is interesting. I'll try that.

I'm not sure I understand option 2, though. I have a pre-populated collection of items for the combobox.